# Website not identifying multiple tables during webscrape

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I've been trying to learn web scraping techniques and hit a wall on this one issue. I know VBA isn't the best tool for web scraping but at my job we don't have the ability to use Python or other tools. Only Excel and VBA. Main goal is scrape table data from various websites and for the most part with sites using one table it is fine but I came across a website with multiple tables and I wasn't able to isolate that table or even pull all the tables onto an Excel sheet. My current code only picks up the first Table and I tried modifying the code to pick up the point per game table and I could not figure it out.

If anyone can help, I've been at this for days.

Thanks in advance.

```
    Sub GetHTMLDocumentXML()

Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDOC As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

XMLPage.Open "GET", "https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/TOR/2020.html", False
XMLPage.send

HTMLDOC.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

ProcessHTMLPage HTMLDOC


End Sub

Sub ProcessHTMLPage(HTMLPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)

    Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Integer


    Set HTMLTables = HTMLPage.getElementsByTagName("table")

    For Each HTMLTable In HTMLTables

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("A1").Value = HTMLTable.className
        .Range("B1").Value = Now
    End With

        RowNum = 2

        For Each HTMLRow In HTMLTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
           'Debug.Print vbTab & HTMLRow.innerText
            ColNum = 1
            For Each HTMLCell In HTMLRow.Children
                Cells(RowNum, ColNum) = HTMLCell.innerText
                ColNum = ColNum + 1
            Next HTMLCell

            RowNum = RowNum + 1
        Next HTMLRow

    Next HTMLTable


End Sub
```

Comment: You're only getting the page source, so if there's any dynamic content added after page load, you will not see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the tabular content in that page are not dynamic; rather, they are commented out. To interact with them you need to first kick out those vicious signs `<!--`, `-->` which do not let your script access them.

This is how you can scrape the table titled as `Per Game` using xhr:

```
Sub FetchData()
    Dim post As Object, trow As Object
    Dim S$, R&, C&

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/TOR/2020.html", False
        .send
        S = Replace(Replace(.responseText, "<!--", ""), "-->", "")
    End With

    With CreateObject("HTMLFile")
        .body.innerHTML = S
        For Each post In .getElementById("per_game").Rows
            For Each trow In post.Cells
                C = C + 1: Cells(R + 1, C) = trow.innerText
            Next trow
            C = 0: R = R + 1
        Next post
    End With
End Sub
```